# React Native Expo Start ignores typescript errors

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

I'm using Expo with Typescript, and when running with `expo start` (and potentially building), it ignores my TypeScript errors.

VS Code will still show an error, but I can reload the App and run it on my phone in Expo Go (potentially leading to runtime errors).

How can I change this behavior, so that compilation errors result in an error when I try to reload/run/build the app?

My tsconfig looks like this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true
  },
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base"
}
```

(I added `noEmitOnError` to see if that helped, it doesn't seem to change the behavior either way)

Comment: Do you mean to say expo start should fail if there is any TS error?

Comment: @GokulKulkarni Correct. I'd like the TypeScript errors to fail fast.

Comment: thats an interesting thing, I had not thought of till now, but I do not think that will be possible. I will do some research on my and get back to you.

Comment: @GokulKulkarni Let me know what you find. I actually just ran into a bug because of this. I could of course set up tsc to watch for changes and alert me, but it would be annoying have 2 terminals be out of sync like that

Comment: please check if this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58459262/why-does-my-react-native-app-build-successfully-despite-typescript-compiler-erro

Comment: @GokulKulkarni yeah, that's very useful. I understand what's happening now, but there's gotta be some way to make it fail fast. It might need changes to the expo tool though, so that it pre-runs TSC without emitting JS, and displays the TS errors if there are any before proceeding. Any other ideas for something I could do on my end for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i didnt appreciate the response from [the expo team](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/8273#issuecomment-627585714) saying it would be unwise to check something like this.

imo a build should fail at the very least when a name cannot be found [TS2304](https://typescript.tv/errors/#TS2304) or cannot be found but is similar [TS2552](https://typescript.tv/errors/#TS2552) which would cause a runtime error.

here is a way around this:

```bash
! npx tsc --noEmit | grep 'TS2552\|TS2304'
```

- `!`: invert the exit code (because grep will return 0 if a match is found and 1 if not)
- `tsc --noEmit`: builds without outputting to a dir (effectively to find these sorts of build errors)
- `|`: pipe the output from the noEmit build to the next command
- `grep 'TS2552\|TS2304'`: look for the TS error 2552 or 2304

(you can add any other rules to look for with `\|<rule>`, the `\|` is a way of escaping the `or` in grep)

you can add this to your package scripts so it can be used to prefix other commands like local / deployment etc using `&&` or the `pre<scriptname>` syntax. if it exits 0 then `&&` will continue to the next script, if it exits 1 then it will stop and fail early, the same is true for the prescript.

example scripts / usage:

(note the double `\\` escape for json)

> with short circuit

```json
"scripts": {
  "check:tsc": "! tsc --noEmit | grep 'TS2552\\|TS2304'",
  "ios": "yarn run check:tsc && npx expo run:ios",
  ...
}
```

> with prescript

running `yarn run ios` will now begin with `yarn run check:tsc`

```json
"scripts": {
  "check:tsc": "! tsc --noEmit | grep 'TS2552\\|TS2304'",
  "preios": "yarn run check:tsc",
  "ios": "npx expo run:ios",
  ...
}
```

hope this helps someone.